# How to add more padding bellow a TextView when the keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When i have TextField inside ScrollView and tap on it the keyboard is shown as expected. But it seems that the TextField is moved up just enough to show the input area but i want to be moved enough so that is visible in its whole. Otherwise it looks cropped. I couldn't find a way to change this behaviour.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text:String = ""

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      VStack(spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(1...12, id: \.self) {
          Text("\($0)…")
            .frame(height:50)
        }
        TextField("Label..", text: self.$text)
          .padding(10)
          .background(.white)
          .cornerRadius(10)
          .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
              .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 1)
          )
      }
      .padding()
      .background(.red)
    }
  }
   
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a .safeAreaInset modifier.

```
  @State var text:String = ""

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      VStack(spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(1...12, id: \.self) {
          Text("\($0)…")
            .frame(height:50)
        }
        TextField("Label..", text: self.$text)
          .padding(10)
          .background(.white)
          .cornerRadius(10)
          .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
              .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 1)
          )
      }
      .padding()
      .background(.red)
    }.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) { //this will push the view when the keyboad is shown
        Color.clear.frame(height: 30)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide additional `padding` to the view (and it works even in iOS 13 and 14):

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text:String = ""

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
      VStack(spacing: 10) {
        ForEach(1...12, id: \.self) {
          Text("\($0)…")
            .frame(height:50)
        }
        TextField("Label..", text: self.$text)
          .padding(10)
          .background(.white)
          .cornerRadius(10)
          .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
              .stroke(.blue, lineWidth: 1)
          )
          .padding(.bottom, 32) //here, set as much pasding as you want
      }
      .padding()
      .background(.red)
    }
  }
   
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, SwiftUI ignores the padding around a text field when it scrolls to it; it scrolls to the bottom border of the text field itself, ignoring any padding around it which results in exactly the second screenshot OP posted (still true with iOS 16).