# How to add more padding below a TextView when the keyboard is shown and enable button clicks in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, textfield

I wanna give my textfield some extra space while SwiftUI is automatically scrolling to it. As described in this question: [How to add more padding below a TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820994/how-to-add-more-padding-bellow-a-textview-when-the-keyboard-is-shown). With the answer from this one it works fine: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/699111 but cause I am manipulating the safe area of the view my button touches are not accepted anymore if they are outside of the safe area.

```
ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Spacer(minLength: 1000)
            TextField("Textfield 1", text: $text)
                .padding(30)
            Button {
                print("Button tapped")
            } label: {
                Text("Click this button")
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 1000)
        }
    }
    .keyboardAvoiding()
```

This example code shows the problem. If I am selecting the TextField and the keyboard appears there's enough space below but If I am clicking at the button nothing happens. Any idea to work around this behaviour or any other way to add more padding below the TextField in SwiftUI?